# How can you delete a table in SQL that was created with a reserved word/key word?

Tags: sql

I created a table in php with the name like using the following syntax

```
create table like
```

and when I wanted to delete it, it does not get deleted.

Can someone help me?

Comment: `drop table "like"`? Perhaps you need to add `cascade` at the end, if there are objects depending on the table - beware, with cascade, those objects will be dropped too!

Comment: `DROP TABLE [like]`.

Comment: The database engine, which you didn't identify, is relevant.

Comment: Note that square brackets are product specific, and SQL Server can also use ANSI SQL's double quotes for delimited identifiers...

Answer (score 1):

In a standard compliant DBMS you need to use:

```
drop table "LIKE";
```

Depending on how you created it, you might need to use lowercase as quoted identifiers are case sensitive in SQL:

```
drop table "like";
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code.

```
--CREATE TABLE [like ] (ID int)
  DROP TABLE [like]
```